# How to: BitmapRegionDecoder using String pathName to the drawable directory

Tags: java, android, bitmap, drawable, pathname

Okay so I am making an app to play Blackjack for a class on Android, and am visually displaying the cards. I would like to use the BitmapRegionDecoder to be most efficient at loading my cards, which are all displayed in one file. Here's my code:

```
BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance("res/drawable/cards.png", false);
Bitmap img = decoder.decodeRegion(new Rect(num, suit, num + 1, suit + 1), null);
```

I know that "res/drawable/cards.png" is not the right way to give the path due to all of the error messages I get, but I don't know what I should use for the path instead. Please help, and thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [newInstance (InputStream is, boolean isShareable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html#newInstance%28java.io.InputStream,%20boolean%29) method instead :

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.cards)
BitmapRegionDecoder regionDecoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(is, false);
```

Comment: openRawResource expects a *raw* resource. E.g. put the file in /res/raw/cards.png and load it with ''getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cards)''